# Why is there a black spot on my normals? Only appears on mesh, not on normal texture

Tags: normals, texture-baking, baking

This is what it looks like, coupled with the UV Editor showing my normal texture
[image]

Here is me selecting the portion it is at, and as you can see it does not appear on my normal texture. [image]

Why is it doing this, and how do I solve it?

Comment: hello could you please pack your image and share your file?